# ¿Interés personal en feedback sobre votos negativos?

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

¿Estarían de acuerdo en que cada usuario mediante un campo en su perfil, pregunta o respuesta pueda controlar lo siguiente?:

- Si un tercero desea dejar un voto negativo en una de mis preguntas o respuestas, este se vea forzado a dejar un comentario.
- Si un tercero desea dejar un voto negativo y no hay comentarios, forzar a dejar un comentario.

***¿Cómo se llamaría?***

*Forzado de feedback.*

***¿Por qué?***

Si alguien piensa dejar un voto negativo personalmente me gustaría recibir un feedback y contexto del voto, a saber por qué lo está haciendo, más si no hay ningún otro comentario en la pregunta o respuesta.

La intención de esto es disuadir los votos de castigo y/o venganza que sabemos que existen pero no existe un mecanismo que lo evidencie.

La segunda intención de esto es poder tener una mejor percepción y orientación de parte de la comunidad activa que está interesada en orientar a los usuarios.

***¿Qué ganamos?***

Esto daría origen a una idiosincrasia (cultura) de comunicación efectiva, que muy a veces no se da con los usuarios nuevos (NO me refiero a debates). Con el hecho de que se cumpla el concepto/objetivo de aclaratoria es suficiente.

***¿Por qué no dar este paso?***

La idea de esto es implementar un mecanismo que sirva de apoyo a la culturización/inducción al sitio de los nuevos y viejos usuarios. Ser más empático no quiere decir que vayamos a aceptar preguntas de peor calidad, lo que esto supone es mejorar la calidad de preguntas sin afectar negativamente la percepción de los usuarios en nuestra comunidad.

***¿Existen ya herramientas?***

Los mecanismos que he visto actualmente aunque funcionen para objetivos predeterminados, han fallado en la socialización y el enriquecimiento del sitio. Durante los últimos meses las visitas al sitio han caído y no necesariamente porque ahora exista la I.A., estamos ante una población de nuevos usuarios que al recibir comentarios como "si no te gusta te puedes ir" obviamente no se quedarán a formar parte de la comunidad. Somos nosotros quienes cerramos la puerta a nuevos usuarios al no aceptar nuestros errores y falencias y pensar que lo que se viene haciendo desde que se creó el sitio continuará siendo lo correcto y no estar abiertos a innovar en nuevos aspectos culturales.

> *Lamentablemente no existe una estadística para medir lo aquí expuesto.*

***La propuesta final:***

En lugar de mostrar la banda superior de sugerencia de dejar un comentario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Remplazarlo por un box el cual permita escribir un comentario anónimo que pueda ser *trackeable* por los moderadores o escoger comentarios prediseñados a modo de aclaratoria, incluso ambos podrían ser buena opción.

Esto solo afectaría a aquellos usuarios que ha activado esta opción en su perfil, pregunta o respuesta: si el usuario no lo activa, el sitio seguiría funcionando como lo hace actualmente.

La idea de esto, es que el usuario que lo activa está abierto a recibir y quiere recibir feedback específicamente de los votos negativos o de quienes creen que la pregunta/respuesta se lo merece.

Comment: En [el centro de ayuda](/help/privileges/vote-down) se explica de qué manera deberían utilizarse los votos negativos. Que haya usuarios que los utilicen con otros motivos es otra cosa.

Comment: Y si esto tuviera la muy remota posibilidad de implementarse, ¿qué es lo siguiene? ¿Justificar el motivo de cierre cuando la publicación tiene 0 votos negativos?

Comment: Más allá de la propuesta, esto suena a dos cosas: imposición y exclusividad. Yo como AP **impongo** que se deje un comentario si alguien desea votar negativa mi publicación, y por otro lado, mis publicaciones pasan a ser exclusivas para el voto negativo, es decir, sólo aquellos que dejen el comentario podrán plasmar su voto negativo. Entonces, ya no sólo hablamos de un sitio *tóxico* (como siempre lo han referido) sino además, impositivo y exclusivo. Bravo.

Comment: Interesante argumento: *si no te gusta, simplemente no votes, no comentes y no pierdes el tiempo*, el mismo que es atacado cuando se aplica a las normas del sitio. *Cosas tenedes, Cid, que farán fablar las piedras*.

Comment: es correcto solo que hay una gran diferencia: mi argumento es crear un saludable ambiente de trabajo, mientras que tu estas coarteando y justificando por que no te gustaria implementarlo...

Comment: Para que este sistema funcione, los usuarios deberian aceptar esos comentarios y las criticas que les puedan hacer, y viendo como evolucionan estos temas ultimamente por aqui y en el chat, solo generaria mas debate innecesario ¿para que? ¿Mejorar una pregunta? Si quieres saber como hacer buenas preguntas y que tu contenido sea bien recibido por la comunidad, en el [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) tienes toda la información

Comment: @Marc te recomiendo leer nuevamente la publicación.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 La he leido varias veces, y sigo penando lo mismo. Te voy a poner un ejemplo asi lo entiendes mejor: Alguien hace una pregunta, alguien le deja un comentario votandote negativo, él no está de acuerdo con ese comentario y entonces ¿que? ¿se va al chat o a un mod a quejarse de que alguien le ha votado negativo? Esto es lo que lleva pasando estas ultimas semanas en el chat, no creo que lo que propones mejore nada, de hecho creo que lo va a empeorar, a parte de hacer perder mas tiempo a la gente que realmente quiere ayudar.

Comment: @Marc entonces tu propones eliminar los comentarios por que la gente siempre se va a aquejar con un mod o en un chat de los comentarios???

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Yo no he dicho eso, te he puesto un ejemplo claro de que es lo que pasará. Si ya se quejan ahora por los votos negativos, imaginate si un Anonimo les deja un comentario diciendo el porque del negativo y ese usuario no está de acuerdo. A parte de perder el tiempo dejando el comentario del negativo, encima vamos a tener mas publicaciones como esta o mas crispación en el chat por estos temas

Comment: yo puse un ejemplo de lo que esta pasando hoy día que es una realidad... no trabajo con supuestos...

Comment: Con esta medida, los usuarios que ya están rebotados porque les han puesto un negativo lo iban a estar aún más porque tampoco les ha gustado el comentario del negativo, por lo que habría aún más discusiones inútiles en meta y aún más fricción entre usuarios. Además cuando se fuerza a escribir un campo, la gente acaba o escribiendo "dsfsdfak" o algún tipo de mensaje genérico. Ej: "La respuesta no es acertada" que no aclara nada y el usuario se queda igual que si le hubiesen puesto un negativo sin comentarios.

Comment: @ordago entonces es mucho mejor la solucion del voto negativo sin contexto?

Comment: No es mucho mejor, pero es menos polémica y / o problemática.

Comment: No se debe combinar la etiqueta obligatorias [meta-tag:característica-nueva] con otras etiquetas. Esta debería reservarse a casos en los que se propone un cambio concreto y factible de realizar por los moderadores del sitio o los gerentes de comunidad sin intervención de los desarrolladores. Cuando se requiera intervención de los desarrolladores debería orientarse a opciones que se puedan configurar para cada sitio. En los casos que se vean afectados otros sitios debería publicarse en [meta.se].

Comment: Punto y aparte de lo anterior, me parece que es bueno discutir lo que aquí se ha propuesto, sólo que se trata de algo bastante complejo que implica no sólo cambiar el software, sino también a los usuarios ( convencimiento, educación, ...) y eso es muy, pero muy difícil.

Comment: @Wicket para nada ... ya la camarilla hablo ... segun todos los comentarios aqui y en el chat, esta propuesta es imposible de llevar a cabo, he incluso es preferible dejar votos negativos sin comentarios ... ya que representa mucho trabajo y se poierde el anonimato ...

Comment: Hay asuntos que no deben limitarse a "camarillas" pero hay otros que está muy bien que se resuelvan rápido. Si las "camarillas" ayudan a resolver los asuntos que conviene se resuelvan rápido y lo hacen propositivamente, perfecto.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Si sigues pensando que esto es un complot en contra de tu persona (o usuario), vas muy equivocado, quizas deberias hacertelo mirar

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Estoy seguro que se ha violado en código de conducta; he intentado comunicarme con la moderación y con la comunidad sobre el tema en este espacio: [¿Interés personal en feedback sobre votos negativos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5558/inter%c3%a9s-personal-en-feedback-sobre-votos-negativos) y prácticamente ha sido boicoteado de todas las formas posibles...

Desde hace algún tiempo he venido siendo víctima de votos negativos de venganza o disuasorios o de castigo como le dicen normalmente a esos votos que no cumplen con el objetivo de la herramienta de votos positivos y negativos....

A pesar de pedir apoyo a la comunidad simplemente su respuesta ha sido que no les interesa ya que yo no soy nadie y no represento ningún interés para nadie y soy el único afectado... el 0.00001%

Lamento mucho el poco profesionalismo de los moderadores del sitio en español y que ven la situación y no hacen nada, simplemente se escudan en decir que no tienen nada que puedan hacer, he comentado lo mismo con otros moderadores de otros sitios en inglés y me dicen que la moderación del sitio en español es pésima para no utilizar palabras altisonantes más acertadas.

La frustracion y el estres, de participar en esta comunidad se ha convertido en un problema de salud para mi, por eso he tomado la descicion de abandonar esta comunidad por segunda vez, ya que eldia de hoy me he percatado que no soy yo el del problema.

Comment: A la comunidad le interesa mejorar, esto que propones no es una mejora, por lo tanto no interesa.

Comment: no veo a nadie proponiendo mejoras...

Comment: Si le interesara lo suficiente, le darían prioridad al error de moderación. Yo fui testigo de un trato exclusivo, y no vi a nadie tratando de justificar por que se dió ese trato cuando lo reporté en meta. Por lo que asumo que hay favoritismos o excepciones a las normas

Comment: @Marc para mi es un intento de mejorarla.

Comment: @DanteS. Es una propuesta como las miles que ha habido, pero no es válida, tiene muchos mas peros que pros, y no lo digo yo, lo hemos dicho muchos usuarios, por eso tiene los votos negativos que tiene, porque no es una buena propuesta de mejora

Comment: @marc entonces, si es una mejora. Solo que tiene más peros

Comment: @DanteS. Es una propuesta de mejora, incorrecta, una mejora será cuando se implemente, cosa que en este caso, no (creo) que pase

Comment: @Marc "eso que propones no es una mejora" te estás contradiciendo

Comment: @DanteS. Tengo que explicarte la diferencia entre "Mejora" y "Propuesta"?

Comment: Entiendo. Tenés razón.

Comment: A veces hace falta leer un poco mas, la comprensión lectora tambien es importante

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 lamento la situación. Que te mejores. A veces, es mejor dejar ir las cosas, con distancia si es necesario. Te lo digo por experiencia. Igual, creo que si reportas tu situación con evidencia, en lugar de proponer una posible mejora, te podrían escuchar. Suerte.

Comment: Lo primero es cuidar la salud. Si participar en algo como esta comunidad no te hace bien es comprensible que desistas en continuar participando. Una vez dicho esto, desconozco cómo ha sido la evolución de tus publicaciones. Lamentablemente las características de la plataforma están limitadas a favorecer ciertas cosas. Todo lo demás depende enteramente de los usuarios. El encontrar eco o no tiene efectos emocionales pero aún así deberíamos poder continuar llevando un convivencia civilizada. Lamentablemente el sistema no ayuda a entender la naturaleza real de los votos.

Answer (score 3):

Yo simpatizo con la idea central, pero no veo que vaya a pasar pronto ya que lo que se está proponiendo es contrario a al menos uno de los principios fundamentales de la plataforma pública de preguntas y respuestas de [Stack Overflow, Inc.](https://stackoverflow.co).

Sin embargo, no me sorprendería estar equivocado ya que últimamente la compañía, aparentemente está dando patadas de ahogado intentando resolver algo que a la mayoría de los "usuarios" que participamos regularmente no nos importa. No les ha importado denostar a quienes dedican más tiempo a salvaguardar los sitios lo que llevado a la huelga de moderación.

El principio fundamental del que estoy hablando sustenta el sistema de votes el cual es una característica fundamental de la plataforma. Si bien a los usuarios con reputación apenas arriba de la necesaria para tener el privilegio de votar abajo se le muestra un mensaje sugiriendo dejar un comentario que ayuda a mejorar la publicación, es fundamental mantener la privacidad de los votos por lo que si se hiciera obligatorio dejar un comentario estos también debería ser anónimos, sin embargo, el hacer los comentarios obligatorios demandaría más tiempo a los usuarios y reduciría el número de publicaciones sobre las que podrían votar.

En un sitio como [Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com) quizás no sea tan relevante pero en la joya de la corona, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com), es algo que tendría un impacto negativo en cuanto a la cantidad de publicaciones "moderadas".

Por lo anterior, salvo que se considere que lo propuesto aquí se pueda configurar sitio por sitio, veo muy difícil que tenga el apoyo de un gran número de usuarios activos en sitios como [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) y [Stack Overflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com).

Algo que tendría mayores posibilidades de tener buena aceptación sería que en lugar de hacer obligatorio el dejar comentarios, otorgar una puntos de reputación en lugar de quitarlos; recuerda que los votos negativos podrían restar reputación al votante.

Comment: Hola, a cual principio te refieres?, he hecho algunas aclaraciones en el post.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Por favor, lee de nuevo el post, despacio, con una taza de té o café, ya que lo menciono. Yo haré lo mismo otro día; no descarto que le pueda faltar claridad o se pueda reestructurar para facilitar una mejor comprensión.

Comment: es que yo tambien soy malo redactanto ... no es mi fuerte ... puedo tener una buena idea pero a lo mejor no la se expresar correctamente.

Comment: aclaro el anonimato del comentario amarrado al voto es anonimo, y la idea es que el usuario pueda configurarlo en su perfil, por pregunta o respuesta ... en pocas palabras aunque se implemente si el usuario no lo activa no pasara nada ...

Comment: @MauricioContreras No es forma de mostrar que estás en desacuerdo. La ironía y sarcasmos como burla son causa de reporte de abuso.

Comment: No utilizo la ironía o sarcasmo como burla, sino como una herramienta de debate: *Irony is a literary device that contrasts expectations and reality. Storytellers use ironic situations to create humor, suspense, and an emphasis on a particular subject. __By highlighting the incongruity of a situation or action, irony draws attention to a plot point, character trait, or thematic argument.__*

Comment: @MauricioContreras el sarcasmo y la ironía no tiene cabida en el debate sano.. lo que busca es confrontación y eso no produce nada bueno. no buscas entender buscas menospreciar y no aportas nada positivo. hasta el momento lo único que ha hecho es una pataleta...   

Comment: @MauricioContreras Tu comentario inicial ha sido demaciado breve para comunicar una objeción o crítica constructiva. Si tu intención es debatir, sería conveniente que   tus comentarios fueran más amplios o mejor aún, publica una respuesta para que objeción tenga mayor visibilidad.

Comment: Les recuerdo que ironía y sarcasmo no son exactamente lo mismo :)

Comment: @padaleiana no son lo mismo pero usarlos como burla, o sin el apropiado desarrollo, está mal por no ser constructivos.

Comment: Por eso. Lo que mencionás es sarcasmo (cuando tiene como objetivo la burla, "siendo malos"), no ironía.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con el ultimo parrafo. Si damos puntos de reputación por el voto negativo, muchos votarían negativo solo para favorecer su reputación, incluso si la preguntano merecía realmente ese voto. Por lo demás, de acuerdo

Comment: @MauricioContreras considero que decir "Vamos dando negativo a todo lo que veo mal parado y encima me recompensan. Me apunto, dónde tengo que firmar?" es burlesco por lo menos y no aporta a la discusión. Lo demás si.

Comment: Pasa que cuando alguien se equivoca en una publicación es posible corregirlo, cuando alguien se equivoca en un cierre es posible reabrir, pero cuando alguien se equivoca en votar??? El problema no es el voto, si no el mal uso que algunos les dan y eso en el anonimato hace imposible corregirlo

Comment: @Yussef como dije en mi respuesta, considero que el problema es la comunidad, no el anonimato

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que esto no tiene tanta relación con la propuesta planteada aquí. Pero creo que es importante resaltarlo.

---

##### el error de moderación

Si el punto es reducir las preguntas de baja calidad y hacer un ambiente amistoso, no creo que el tema de los comentarios anonimos obligatorios según pregunta (lo cual no funcionaría por que la gente podría cualquier cosa, lo que sucede con el bot comunidad) sea el enfoque más fuerte.

Tratar de mencionar normas poco firmes en forma de comentarios anonimos no nos va a llevar a ninguna parte. A donde vas a guiar? Al centro de ayuda? Tiene discrepancias con respecto a las verdaderas "normas". Guiar aqui, meta, mejor, pero la comunidad hace excepciones a las normas escritas en meta.

##### contrapropuesta

Esto requiere que la comunidad se de cuenta del error de moderación y estandarice y aclare las normas:

Podríamos dejar las normas más claras, no solo en meta, también en el centro de ayuda. Además de tender al cumplimiento de estas, sin excepción. También aclarar explicitamente a usuarios nuevos al crearse la cuenta nuestra filosofía de que el voto negativo no es un ataque personal.

De esta manera, orientamos a los usuarios mejor con un estandar claro que seguir, reduciríamos las preguntas de baja calidad y, por lo tanto, los casos aparentemente no amistosos de la comunidad también bajarían en número.

##### esto solucionaría totalmente el problema?

No, y no se puede resolver del todo, solo reducir. Si un usuario evita todo intento de comunicación automatica o de la comunidad, ve el voto negativo y se lo toma personal, no hay mucho que se pueda hacer.

Comment: como garantizas el cumplimiento de la objetividad al emitir votos? **nuestra filosofía de que el voto negativo no es un ataque personal.*** esto es una falacia...

Comment: @ArkanisGK507 Pareciera que la mayoría de la gente no hace ataques personales. Si viste algún ataque personal, pasame el escenario. Lamentablemente, es imposible garantizarlo, pero si se puede reducir, lo que ya hace el sitio restringiendo el número de votos emitido. Si querés reducirlo aún más, requiere que la comunidad cambie de parecer. Para que sirve una ley si solo el 10% de la población la cumple y nadie la hace cumplir?

Comment: Yo ya intenté hacer llamados a la reflexión, casi no tuvieron efecto. Esto me recuerda a la comunidad de Pinturillo. Tienen normas pero nadie las respeta. Soy el unico que va contra la corriente en pinturillo.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que esto es más una discusión teórica que practica, porque no está en ninguno de nosotros poder cambiar/agregar características del sitio.

La realidad es que el voto es personal y anónimo, y aun cuando hay reglas para votar, hay usuarios que se saltan las reglas. A mi más de uno me lo ha dicho abiertamente.

En lo personal, hasta me gustan los negativos, si no recibo una buena dosis de ello a la semana siento que no he respondido lo suficiente.

El problema está en los usuarios nuevos, en muchos casos lo sienten como un ataque personal, y estos terminan preguntando en otras plataformas. Hace poco apareció una estadísticas de la caída en las visitas de SOen, que concuerda con lo caída evidente de preguntas en este sitio.

La propuesta no me parece mala, a mi lo del anonimato nunca me ha parecido correcto, pero creo más productivo conversar en lo que realmente podemos hacer.

En mi apreciación se es más riguroso con usuarios nuevos que con usuarios viejos, tanto en las preguntas como en las respuesta. (es cosa que revisen preguntas de usuarios con alto puntaje, y verán una cantidad desmedida de votos positivos)

Yo hago un llamado a los usuarios a que:

- Si ves que una publicación tiene más negativos de los que se merece, vótale positivo
- Si la pregunta está aceptable vota positivo
- Si la respuesta es aceptable vota positivo

*(esto en relación a publicaciones de usuario hasta 1k de pts, el resto dan los mismo :P)*

Un voto positivo vale más que uno negativo, y hay muchos que no gastamos nuestros votos diarios

Comment: Esto: *Si ves que una publicación tiene más negativos de los que se merece, vótale positivo*, sería lo opuesto al "voto castigo". Lo llamaremos "voto compasivo", y luego el sitio se llamará "Stack Caritas" y el lema será: *aunque tu publicación sea un asco, por ser nuevo, te perdonamos y toma tu pack de votos positivos para que seas feliz y no nos abandones, carita feliz, carita feliz, carita feliz*

Comment: Por cierto, [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/600460/dibujar-pol%c3%adgono-con-css) no pertenece a un usuario nuevo, tiene más de 1 año en el sitio. Los negativos en este caso, ¿estarían justificados? Si es así, pues vaya discriminación. Pero en fin.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507, no. No tengo nada en contra de tu propuesta, no la he votado ni up ni down. Yo sólo me refiero a lo que pone esta respuesta: *En mi apreciación se es más riguroso con usuarios nuevos que con usuarios viejos*. No critico las propuestas, sólo hago preguntas que cuestionen las propuestas. Este es el sitio para debatir. No el chat, no el sitio principal. Este es el sitio. Pides feedback, te lo estoy dando, pero parece que no es el feedback que esperas, entonces no entiendo el propósito de la propuesta, si de plano en la misma ya vas contra argumentando el feedback.

Comment: Catalogar los argumentos de buenos o malos no es precisamente algo que podamos hacer desde la perspectiva del *otro*. En mi opinion, los argumentos se sostienen o no se sostienen. Lo de la *camarilla* es simple conjetura, una especie de teoría de la conspiración. *Yo me reúno en privado con ciertos usuarios para ponerme de acuerdo en cómo "manejar" el sitio a nuestro antojo*. Es simpático pensar que alguien crea eso, como si no tuviera yo suficientes cosas con verdadera importancia como para estar confabulado con *la camarilla*. Si parece que ahora, compartir opinión, es apología del delito.

Comment: pues estas justificando el mal uso del sistema de votos ... que te puedo decir al respecto ...

Comment: @MauricioContreras Sobre tu primer comentario: Yo dije "mas negativos de los que se merece", he visto casos donde lo machacan con -4 en un hora y no era para tanto, entonces ahí aplica el "voto compasivo". Luego para las otras publicaciones mencioné que votáramos positivamente cuando fueran "aceptables" y no esperar que sean perfectas. Y es que el estándar de facto es que a los nuevos no se les perdona nada y para los viejos es "stack caritas", no quiero dar ejemplos, porque no me quiero pelear con nadie, pero es cosa de revisar preguntas de algunos usuarios con mayor puntaje

Comment: Sobre el 2do comentario: Ese usuario no lleva un año, hizo una pregunta hace un año y volvió a hacer la misma pregunta hoy, es decir en un año ha entrado 2 días. y cuando se le pidió que mejorara su pregunta lo hizo, y ahora es una pregunta de lo más aceptable. Y ES JUSTAMENTE EL PUNTO, porque no esperar un tiempo razonable a que el usuario pueda editar su pregunta y no machacarlo con negativos prematuros.

Comment: Sobre el 3er comentario, supongo que no era para mi, porque yo jamás he hablado de camarilla y es que tampoco pienso que exista. Y para aclarar el asunto, hay un conjunto de usuarios que son los más activos en el chat (entre esos estas tu) de los cuales tengo la mejor opinión. Y dudo que el problema esté entre esos usuarios, para mi son otros. Mas o menos intuyo quienes son, pero obviamente no tengo como comprobarlo.

Comment: Puedo coincidir en que el problema esté en los usuarios nuevos que no reciban bien los votos negativos, pero eso no justifica el que se deba de cambiar el sistema que ya existe, la interpretación depende de cada uno, no podemos saber o predecir como un usuario va a interpretar los votos, el como funcionan y para que sirve ya está escrito, es problema del usuario nuevo que no se lea el funcionamiento del sitio para saber como funciona.

Answer (score -1):

Si bien comparto la idea base, creo que debe ser implementada en la totalidad de usuarios, todos aquel que vote negativo, tiene que dejar un comentario, ahora, bien, teniendo en cuenta la idea de que no se debe debatir sobre los mismos (ni generar resquemores), el comentario debería ser anónimo (para el OP, no para el sistema), de esta forma, mataríamos dos pájaros de un tiro, por u lado, se termina el voto castigo, y por otro (a mi entender más importante) educamos al OP.
En el caso de que el voto sea injustificado, este se denuncia, y el sistema actúa.
Finalizando, todo muy lindo... todavía esperamos que modifiquen el chat...

Comment: lo he considerado correcto y lo he agregado a la propuesta, puedes ver la actualizacion.

Comment: Suena utópico, la verdad. El voto castigo eliminado del sitio. Pero, hay un fallo en esta lógica. Cómo determino que el voto es de castigo si me dejan un comentario ambiguo o con "buena pinta" (digamos casi generado por chatGPT). ¿Es un voto castigo disfrazado de buenas intenciones? Vamos a darle a los moderadores diamantados la responsabilidad de catalogar los votos que "sospecho" me han dado como castigo? No es esta propuesta un traje a medida para un tipo específico de usuarios? No lo sé, yo tengo mi opinión al respecto, pero no basta sólo mi opinión.

Comment: @MauricioContreras, al final, tienes que haber alguien que juzgue la idoneidad del comentario, si el comentario no es una causa válida para el voto negativo, se le llama la atención al votante.

Comment: @MarcePuente y ese es el gran temor: 1) el trabajo de evaluar que los comentarios sean objetivos al igual que los votos.... y 2) que esto representa mas trabajo.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507, no creo que genere más trabajo, el que exista la posibilidad de que te tiren de las orejas si emites un voto injustificado, haría que prácticamente desaparecieran los "malos votos", por otro lado, solo abría que revisar, aquellos votos que sean denunciados, osea, si yo emito un voto negativo, bien justificado, el OP, no tiene porque denunciarlo, y no genera más trabajo.